# GlassPane not visible over JDialog

Tags: java, swing, visibility

I'm trying to see the `GlassPane` over `JDialog` but I got nothing visible over it. Why does it happen? How can I make the `GlassPane` visible over the `JDialog`?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
public class New_Window extends JDialog {

    public New_Window(int Screen_Index, int Start_Panel, int Length) {
        super(new Frame(Monitors.getInstance().getNextDevice()
                .getDefaultConfiguration()), Title, false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setGlassPane(glassPane);
        getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        JPanel Container = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 2, 2));
        Container.setOpaque(false);
        getContentPane().add(Container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        [...]
    }

}
```

**Note:** I'm using Java version 6 update 24. I'm using a custom `GlassPane` with its `opaque` value set to `false`.

Comment: Please give us fuller code. The glass pane has its opaque value set to false. If you are using default one that is your problem. But I am guessing obviously.

Comment: Im using Version 6 update 24 and Im using custom glassPane and its opaque value set to false

Comment: that does not help , im still could not see the image that im drawing over glasspane at JDialog

Comment: OK. Then the issue is more sever. There must be some bug in your code, can we see it? Make us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), of your code. Where we can see how you assign all variables and where you putt them. You might be surprised that doing so you might see the problem yourself.

Comment: When you post your SSCCE use proper variable names. Variable names should NOT start with an upper cased character. I've never seen a tutorial or book that does this so don't make up your own rules and follow the standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using a Glass Pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane) for a working example. Start with the example code and remove code you don't need.

Comment: In my project ,I can use GlassPane successfully but my program is spread over multiple monitors , main monitor have JFrame and I can see the GlassPane over it , but the other monitors they contains JDialog which I cannot see the GlassPane over it , I think the problem may be at paintComponent function with the Graphics object,what do you think?